# Changing QGIS map from ' bird's eye / aerial view' to normal view?

Tags: qgis, aerial-photography

While working in a map, the map changed in to bird's eye view'. I've managed to get the base layer back into 'normal' view by changing the coordinate reference. The other layers are still in aerial view and on a different 'location' even when I change their cooordinate reference.

Any idea how I can get it all layers back to normal view and on top of the base layer?

Answer (score 4):

What you experience is not an aerial view, but rather a **project** CRS set to decimal degrees, like EPSG:4326. With that, longitudes and latitudes have different scales, if your working area is far from the equator.

To get back to normal view, set the **project** CRS to a projected CRS. If you use basemaps from the Openlayers or QuickMapServices plugin, this should be EPSG:3857. Your local UTM zone should work as well for the second plugin.

You should **NOT**  use `Set Layer CRS` to change the coordinate reference, this would spoil your data. If you did, reset it, or remove and re-add the layers.

Comment: Thanks, it made the base layer look like it should. But the additional shape-files still have het wrong perspective and are on a different position. Can you tell how to reset the CRS? Re-add the layers don't have any effect!

Comment: I've re-add the base layer and changed the CRS and now it's all fine again!

Comment: The whole reason I used EPSG:4326 was so that I can jump to different coordinates by entering latitude/longitude.  So it appears that's a bit more work in that I have to change coordinate systems twice just to jump to a different location on the globe...